# Creating VIEW using EXECUTE ignores USING clause parameter?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a UDF that creates a `VIEW` dynamically using the `USING` clause feature. The problem is, `EXECUTE` will not accept the passed parameter into the `CREATE VIEW` command.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION test(name varchar) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('create or replace view %I as select $1 as id limit 1;',$1) using $1;
    RETURN;
END
$$;
```

Test:

```
select test('tabel_view');
```

Current output:

> SQL Error [42P02]: ERROR: there is no parameter $1
> Where: PL/pgSQL function test(character varying) line 3 at EXECUTE

The same works for `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(name varchar) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('create table %I as select $1 as id limit 1;',$1) using $1;
    RETURN;
END
$$;
```

I am trying this way because string concatenation is prone to SQL injection. Also, the UDF that I am working on will have an array as input.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` is for passing **values** to **DML commands** ("utility commands"). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in
> optimizable SQL commands (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`,
> `MERGE`, and certain commands containing one of these). In other
> statement types (generically called utility statements), you must
> insert values textually even if they are just data values.

Does not work with DDL commands like `CREATE VIEW`. The `SELECT` statement in `CRATE TABLE` is different in that it is treated (and executed) as actual nested `SELECT` statement, where parameter interpolation is implemented. It falls under *"certain commands containing one of these"*.

Concatenate the value as string literal instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(name text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW %1$I AS SELECT %1$L AS id;', $1);
END
$proc$;

CALL test('My View');  -- example with evil name
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SF4JJEwc)

The string literal defaults to type `text`. Add an explicit type cast if you need a different type - like for an array type that you mentioned.

```
...
EXECUTE format('CREATE VIEW %1$I AS SELECT %1$L::text[] AS id;', $1);
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the workaround and insight ! I didn't know it falls under the "certain commands containing one of these", since table creation works perfectly.

Comment: @Zaki: To be clear, `CREATE TABLE` is the one that falls under "certain commands containing one of these", not `CREATE VIEW`.